# Integrating Google Calendar API Into An Application?

Tags: ios, api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to integrate Google Calendar into an Application for say iPhone or Android powered devices?

If so, where would I get started? Becuase, I have read the entire Google Calendar API Documentation and seem to be quite lost on where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample Objective-C application using the Google Calendar API is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m).

Comment: The referenced API is deprecated and has been replaced by this: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest